# Eclipse Neon (4.6) Javascript and Web Developers Package: java compliance level only to 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I've installed Eclipse Neon "Javascript and Web Developers" package, and the Java compiler compliance level only goes to 1.7.  I need 1.8. and I find it ironic that Neon requires java 1.8, but won't set that compliance level. Is this lack of 1.8 a bug or am I just missing a project to get it included?

I'm pretty sure the "Java EE" package would not have this problem, but that flavor has a ton of projects that I don't want and have had trouble with in the past. I want to see if the lighter Javascript package will work for me.

I am running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2, and have the Java 1.8 SDK correctly set up on my system and is the default java and javac. I've also set its JRE as the JRE Runtime in Neon.

Comment: Installed the package how? Also, it doesn't actually contain Java Tools...

Comment: I use the tarball.  I mostly do javascript, but there is some java in the backend, and what I see so far works for me. I just need 1.8, and shouldn' t Neon let me set that?

Comment: Yes, it should. So how were the Java tools installed?

Comment: I have not added any other packages than what I unzipped from the original JS-Neon.  I think that it must come with _some_ tools.  Are you implying that the Javascript & Web Devs has **no knowedge** of java at all?

Comment: No, just that it shouldn't have it in there because it's not in the download. Something must have triggered its installation, but it doesn't sound like it was properly installed. Check for and apply any pending updates from the Help menu.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  You were correct, the Java tools indeed were being put in by a package that I didn't think used them. I've cleaned up, started over and pulled in the Java myself first, and it's all good.